# collapse card with each associated button get clicked

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, django-templates, django-2.2

I am trying to provide unique id to data-toggle but it is not showing the collapse individual for each button, rather than it is showing all open cards.

I have tried to provide a unique id(let say `<button data-target=example></button>` and  in `<div class = collapses id=example></div>`

In this situation for clicking on one button I am getting all buttons cards.

```
{% for task in translator.task_set.all %}
    {% fetching_variable_id as variable_id %}
    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{variable_id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        {{ task.deadline }}
        {% admin_task_status_display task.id as status%}
        <div style="float:right;" class="ml-auto mr-3 "><small>{{status.0}}</small></div>
    </button>

    <div class="collapses" id="{{variable_id}}">
        <div class="row">
            {% for task_card in task.cards.all %}
                <div class="card ml-2" style="width: 15.5rem;">
                    <div class="card-body" style="text-align:justify;">
                         <h5 class="card-context" style="font-size:0.85rem; font-weight:bold;">
                             {{ task_card.context }}
                         </h5>
                    </div>

            {% end for %}
```

I expected if I click a particular button only cards associated with that button will show.

Comment: after fixing code formatting, I see some `</div>` are missing in your code and a closing `{% end for %}` statement is missing too.Complete your code, maybe it will solve your problem.

Comment: see  collapse division is getting closed after {{%end for%}}.And one division is getting closed before  {{%end for%}} .

Comment: And  second  {{%end for%}} is at last after 2 division getting closed